# Excel Solver - can't nail down necessary Constraints in Solver to do my task

Tags: excel, solver

I am having trouble figuring out the correct Constraints I should have to finish a task.

Small description about the task is:

> A, B, C, D, E, F = cities
>
> Manufacturing is being done at A and B factories
>
> Warehouses are in C and D cities
>
> Production must be delivered to E and F cities
>
> Factory A can produce 700kg every month, factory B - 450kg
>
> E demand is at 450kg every month, F - 550kg every month
>
> In the first table are shown the transportation costs between cities
>   per 1 kg
>
> Objective is to get the minimal transportation cost and meet the
>   demand
>
> Process should be like Factory -> Warehouse -> E or F city

I have already started working on the Excel and Solver and am just missing a few constraints that I can't figure out.

Link to Excel: mega.nz/#!FFIwiI7T!gx4c0Bwg3NtEEyqs0Zdnkwbclr0uWOUxW45RkSTn_‌​9k (latest)

Just by looking at the transportation cost table it seems (I think at least) like it should go like: 1) A produced stuff moves to -> B, 2) B and A produced stuff to warehouse C or D, 3) then from C and D to E or F

atm it just goes straight from warehouse C to E for example which isn't possible since C hasn't received from A or B yet.

Answer (score 1):

You're on a [Transshipment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transshipment_problem). Take a look at the constraints at that page.

The constraints that you are missing in your current model concern the *Transshipment nodes* `C and D`. You should state that these are just transit nodes; therefore the quantity entering `C` (resp. `D`) on its column must equal the quantity leaving `C` (resp. `D`) on its row.

To do this:

1- Copy the formula of `H20` into `H21` and `H22`. These will account for what *leaves* from transit nodes `C` and `D`.

2- Copy the formula of `E25`  into `C25` and `D25`. These will account for what *enters* into transit nodes `C` and `D`.

3- Add the constraint that states that what enters `C` should equal what leaves `C` (similar for `D`). This contraint can be entered in array for like this:

```
$H$21:$H$22 = $C$25:$D$25
```

Finally, you can simplify your model by dropping the 3rd table and using the *very powerful* Excel function `SUMPRODUCT`. That is, enter this as your objective function in cell `B29`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B8:F12,B19:F23)
```

This function will do for you the sum of products `Sigma(cij * xij)` without the need to compute each individual product in a different cell with a formula.

Comment: @user3688039 in the sheet you attached, there is a formula in `E25`: `=SUM(D19:D23)`, it sums up the items delivered to the item on the column E. What i am saying is that you should do the same for each of `C` and `D`. So yes I meant copy `E25` to `C25` and `D25`.

Comment: Yeah, so this is what I got to, nice progress but C20 value seems strange?

https://mega.nz/#!FFIwiI7T!gx4c0Bwg3NtEEyqs0Zdnkwbclr0uWOUxW45RkSTn_9k

Comment: @user3688039 For linear programs such as this one, use the `Simplex LP` solver method, not the `GRG non-linear` method. Also check again your constraints, you have so many ones added to the initial, so the problem became non-feasible. The initial one worked for me after I added the indicated constraints; I got: `B-->D = 450`,  `A-->E = 450` and `A-->F = 100`, all else is zero.

Comment: Basically I replaced the 999999's with 0's and thus added extra constraints, else Solver was picking up some of the 99999 as the optimal route and I got a ridiculously high cost. Was your cost fine?

Comment: @user3688039 no because there was no routes with small costs to route all. However, if you modify these values from your initial worksheet, you will observe an interesting solution: modify `C8` and `F10` to some reasonable number, i.e. `5`. This will create a route from `A` to `F` via the transit node `C`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't edit any of the given values. But I had a needless constraint that disallowed E->F transportation (F23 cell). Now the Solver can find a solution.

https://mega.nz/#!cJAhgZaQ!R92h6nLvLED7zAedjhu-VJOkbTp43evL4XSB2cC5GBk

Though I don't get how E->F got 550 production if A-E was only 450?

Comment: The said constraint was'nt needless actually, because `E` is not a production node or a transit node, so nothing can go out of it. Basically you can complete your model by filling all the rows `24,25` and columns `G,H` so that you force these constraints in such a way that *nothing goes out of D and E* (`G22=G23=0`) and *nothing gets into a source node* (`B24=C24=0`). Then write constraints on the sums: `H19:H23 <= G19:G23` and `B25:D25 >= B24:D24`.

Comment: @user3688039 but be careful for cells `G21:G22` and `C24:D24` dont set them to zero, set them to something like `1000` to say that trnasit nodes do not have capacity limit. Try to work out the model a little more using these guidelines :)

Comment: @user3688039 moreover, maybe your model should be further simplified by reducing your matrices: Source nodes `A and B` should not have dedicated columns at all, and similarly sink nodes `E and F` should not have any rows dedicated to them. That's how usually a transportation problem is presented: rows are for sources and columns are for sinks. In transshipment, the transit nodes appear in both.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your continuous help. Some more questions if you don't mind, 

1. "because E is not a production node or a transit node", why E can't be a transit node to reach F, for example? It also has a cost of 2 in the cost table.

2. B25:D25 >= B24:D24 this doesn't seem to target any values, did you mean some other cells?


Current progress:
https://mega.nz/#!xcgAyDxI!tNGrbFJxQ6FeMogWdV_7Pmge4LEVXJSxZB40szv8wck

Results seem better now, but I still haven't applied some of your suggestions since I don't quite understand them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144959/discussion-between-user3688039-and-a-s-h).